Syntax highlight exclusively within a region
I'm trying to add syntax highlighting for arguments with patterns similar to this:
if(GetKey(KEY_SPACE) == KEY_PRESSED)

where a KEY_ match should be highlighted, but only when inside GetKey.
I've tried creating a syntax rule for the top level:
syn match GetKey /\(^\|\s\|(\)GetKey(\(KEY_[_a-zA-Z0-9]\+\))\($\|\s\)/ contains=GetKeyArg contained

and then tried to match the insides of the brackets
syn match GetKeyArg /\(KEY_[_a-zA-Z0-9]\+\)/ contained containedin=GetKey

but both KEY_SPACE and KEY_PRESSED become GetKeyArg. Is there a way to make a syntax match exclusive to a group?

This question is similar to: How can I make a syntax match be contained only inside of a specific syntax region without creating separate files?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
